# Update app without using Google Play Store/App Store, using Shorebird

Tags: flutter

My purpose is I need to update my App without using Google Play Store/App Store.
Then I find the way to match with my need. it's Shoirebird.

I have setup everything done. Until step to validating.

Step 1)
I use CMD "shorebird preview" to emulate Android and use CMD "shorebird release android" for upload to shorebird server. Then I edit some code and use CMD "shorebird patch android" to update new patch, then go to Android emulator, it's working normal, code I updated is really update.

Step 2)
I used CMD "shorebird release android" to create APK file, then I install this APK file to my phone (Android). Then I edit some code and use CMD "shorebird patch android" to update new path, then go to my phone, it's not working, code isn't updated.

I need too known what I do wrong.

Comment: After you released a patch, it gets downloaded to shorebird built app and on the next launch the patch gets applied.

You must use Shorebird Fork of Flutter SDK to build the app and the patches for it to work.

Follow the documentation of shorebird https://docs.shorebird.dev/guides/code_push_quickstart

Comment: I try to use "shorebird preview" (to android emulator), it's working, after I release new path, it updated (after restart app).

But I need to create a APK file, because I need to share to another person to use, but it's not working after I released new path.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.